# How can I display api data in an html list?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website that will be pulling data from an api and displaying the elements in a list. I got this code from another online source, but only the hardcoded data shows, not the data from the api. Is there an issue with my javascript?

Here is my current code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <ul id="myList"></ul>
        <script>

            let displayList = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Berries', 'Watermelon'];

            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon`)
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                data.results.forEach((item) => {
                    displayList.push(item.name)
                })
                console.log(displayList)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`Error fetching: ${err}`)
            });

            var list = document.getElementById("myList");
            displayList.forEach((item) => {
                let li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerText = item;
                list.appendChild(li);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried to put the api pull in a header script tag so it pushes the data before the body is loaded like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            
            let displayList = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Berries', 'Watermelon'];

            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon`)
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                data.results.forEach((item) => {
                    displayList.push(item.name)
                })
                console.log(displayList)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`Error fetching: ${err}`)
            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="myList"></ul>
        <script>

            var list = document.getElementById("myList");
            displayList.forEach((item) => {
                let li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerText = item;
                list.appendChild(li);
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The data from the pokemon api will be logged in the console, but not in the list that the user will see.

NOTE: This is just a proof of concept, the the code will be moved/formatted as needed after, also I will be my own custom-made api for the final project if this information changes anything

Comment: The reason you are seeing this happen is because of the asynchronous nature of http requests in Javascript. While the request is inflight, your code is already iterating over displayList. By moving that code block inside the promise, we can be sure the API request has finished and that the data is available to do work with.

Comment: I see, that makes perfect sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not using async approach for your displaying part. I just added another `then` after your api call to show you possible solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <ul id="myList"></ul>
        <script>

            let displayList = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Berries', 'Watermelon'];

            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon`)
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                var list = document.getElementById("myList");
                data.results.forEach((item) => {
                    displayList.push(item.name);
                    let li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.innerText = item.name;
                    list.appendChild(li);
                })
                console.log(displayList)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(`Error fetching: ${err}`)
            });

             

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I am new to this so async is quite confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the display part again, when you receive your new data. So in `.then` add the following:

```js
.then((data) => {
    data.results.forEach((item) => {
        displayList.push(item.name)
    })
    displayList.forEach((item) => {
       let li = document.createElement("li");
       li.innerText = item;
       list.appendChild(li);
   })
    console.log(displayList)
});
```